Next.js Vercel Domain content mismatch
I created this small Next.js 14 website / crud app and I'm hosting it on Vercel.
The issue is whenever I update content in the admin section of the app (using next.js api routes and revalidatepath), the changes appear as they should on mywebsite.vercel.app but nothing is changed on mywebsite.com (which I added and configured as per Vercel instructions). The only way to update content on the actual .com domain has been to redeploy app.
Anyone knows if this is some caching issue, Next.js or vercel issue, and how do I fix it?
I tried clearing the browser cache, changing Next.js versions, googling, no solutions so far

Not sure what the problem was but redirecting their free subdomain to my domain solved it.

Try this. You can ignore caching
let data = await fetch('https://api.vercel.app/blog', { cache: 'no-store' })

checkout documentation
